# How to open a file and anchor to dedicated line number with vim

Tags: linux, shell, vim

My log always shows errors in this way:

```
lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38
```

Can I copy the above line then open the file with vim and move to line 38?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [file:line - Allows you to open file:line and it does the right thing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin; it sets up autocmds to handle those, so you can pass your `path/to/file:lnum` directly to Vim on the command line and `:edit` such, too!

Answer (score 3):

You can open a file in vim and jump to a specific line by using the `+` syntax:

```
vi lib/rails/rack/logger.rb +38
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put this function in your (bash ?) rc file :

```
vimtoline(){ IFS=: read -r f l <<< "$1"; vim "$f" +"$l"; }
```

then

```
vimtoline lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38
```

will do the trick.

Thanks to chepner for the enhancement.

Comment: No need for `awk`: `vimtoline () { IFS=: read -r f l <<< "$1"; vim "$f" + "$l"; }` This will properly handle files containing whitespace and other special shell characters.